# Use a specific part of code (img src) that I generated using a foreach loop in the page I open using asp-route-id and asp-page

Tags: html, image, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, razor-pages

This is probably really simple and I'm looking in completely the worng place when looking for answers online, so apologies for the noobyness of the question. Here goes...

I am developing a ASP.NET Core Web Application (using Razor Pages) and utilising Entity Framework Core in Visual Studio 2019. I have created a page that generates a bunch of different images and buttons in an OWL2 carousel using foreach based on my model:

```
<div class="owl_@bandModel.BandId owl-carousel owl-theme owl-drag">

    @foreach (var jobTitleModel in bandModel.JobTitles)
    {
        @if (jobTitleModel.ImageType.ImageTypeOption != null)
        {
            switch (jobTitleModel.ImageType.ImageTypeOption)
            {
                case "Apron":
                    <div class="item">
                        @{int randomImg = random.Next(1, Apron);}
                        <img src="~/content/images/map/@jobTitleModel.ImageType.ImageTypeOption/img@(randomImg).svg" type="image/svg+xml" />
                        <a asp-page="/UIMain/Requirements/Index" asp-route-ID="@jobTitleModel.JobTitleId" class="btn btn-outline-primary mb-2 mt-1 btn-block">@jobTitleModel.JobTitle</a>

                    </div>
                    break;
                case "Casual":
                    <div class="item">
                        @{randomImg = random.Next(1, Casual);}
                        <img src="~/content/images/map/@jobTitleModel.ImageType.ImageTypeOption/img@(randomImg).svg" type="image/svg+xml" />
                        <a asp-page="/UIMain/Requirements/Index" asp-route-ID="@jobTitleModel.JobTitleId" class="btn btn-outline-primary mb-2 mt-1 btn-block">@jobTitleModel.JobTitle</a>
                    </div>
                    break;
```

etc...

This is all working fine. However, when the user clicks on the button i.e.

```
<a asp-page="/UIMain/Requirements/Index" asp-route-ID="@jobTitleModel.JobTitleId" class="btn btn-outline-primary mb-2 mt-1 btn-block">@jobTitleModel.JobTitle</a>
```

I would like to be able to take the exact image that was randomly generated and use that on the page that opens.

it would look something like this:

```
<img src="~/content/images/map/Apron/img5.svg" type="image/svg+xml" />
```

So my question is, can this be done? I've explored the asp-all-route-data helper, but I can figure it out. I want it to work in the same way that the asp-route-ID helper does, but I think that this would be wrong because it will add it to the URL.

It's worth pointing out that there isn't any database association with the images, I am having to add them in randomly from the wwwroot/contents folder (using the img#) as a random number, to esure they don't look that same every time.

Thnaks in advance.

***(Thanks for the explaination and the confidence boost Fei Han, sometimes it just helps having someone say that you can do something the way you thought)***

**EDIT TO SHOW HOW I IMPLEMENTED @FeiHan's SUGGESTION:**

Fei Han suggested that I use:

```
<a asp-page="/UIMain/Requirements/Index" asp-route-ID="@jobTitleModel.JobTitleId" asp-route-ImgId="@randomImg" class="btn btn-outline-primary mb-2 mt-1 btn-block">@jobTitleModel.JobTitle</a>
```

The main point being the addition of the **asp-route-ImgId="@randomImg"** helper, however, this wasn't all I needed, as I needed to pass the **ImageType** into the **img src** as well. So I followed the logic and also included an asp-helper-tag for that too i.e. **asp-route-ImgType="@jobTitleModel.ImageType.ImageTypeOption"**.

So my link structure looked like this:

```
<a asp-page="/UIMain/Requirements/Index" asp-route-ID="@jobTitleModel.JobTitleId" asp-route-ImgType="@jobTitleModel.ImageType.ImageTypeOption" asp-route-ImgId="@randomImg" class="btn btn-outline-primary mb-2 mt-1 btn-block">@jobTitleModel.JobTitle</a>
```

Then I moved over to the **Requirements/Index Page** as reference in the link and edited the **Index.cshtml.cs** to include:

```
namespace ProjectName.Pages.UIMain.Requirments
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        public string RndmImgSrc { get; set; }

        public async Task OnGetAsync(int? id, int? ImgId, string ImgType)
        {
                    RndmImgSrc = string.Format("/content/images/map/{0}/img{1}.svg", ImgType, ImgId);
//If you are a proper noob like me, a little heads-up here. You need to remove the "~" symbol from the begining of the URL (~/content/) as the Routing will add the current page route and wont refer to the wwwroot.
        }
    }
}
```

Then in the **Index.cshtml** I added:

```
@page "{ImgType?}/{ImgID?}/{ID?}" //This was just to tidy up the URL
@model ProjectName.Pages.UIMain.Requirments.IndexModel

<img src="@Model.RndmImgSrc" type="image/svg+xml" width="300"/>
```

And hey presto!!! it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want it to work in the same way that the asp-route-ID helper does, but I think that this would be wrong because it will add it to the URL.

You are using  tag to navigate to another page, passing data through URL is ok. You can pass generated Img Id `randomImg`, like below.

```
<div class="item">
    @{int randomImg = random.Next(1, Apron);}
    <img src="~/content/images/map/@jobTitleModel.ImageType.ImageTypeOption/img@(randomImg).svg" type="image/svg+xml" />

    <a asp-page="/UIMain/Requirements/Index" asp-route-ID="@jobTitleModel.JobTitleId" asp-route-ImgId="@randomImg" class="btn btn-outline-primary mb-2 mt-1 btn-block">@jobTitleModel.JobTitle</a>
</div>
```

Besides, if you don't want to pass data `randomImg` as query string or route parameter in URL, you can post generated Id of img via a hidden form, like below.

```
switch (jobTitleModel.ImageType.ImageTypeOption)
{
    case "Apron":
        <div class="item">
            @{int randomImg = random.Next(1, Apron);}
            <img src="~/content/images/map/@jobTitleModel.ImageType.ImageTypeOption/img@(randomImg).svg" type="image/svg+xml" />

            <form method="post" asp-page="/UIMain/Requirements/Index" asp-page-handler="ShowImg" asp-route-ID="@jobTitleModel.JobTitleId">
                <input type="hidden" name="ImgId" value="@randomImg" />
                <input type="submit" class="btnhidden" />
            </form>
            <a asp-page="/UIMain/Requirements/Index" asp-route-ID="@jobTitleModel.JobTitleId" asp-route-ImgId="@randomImg" class="btn btn-outline-primary mb-2 mt-1 btn-block" onclick="return myfunc(this)">@jobTitleModel.JobTitle</a>
        </div>
        break;

    case "Casual":
        <div class="item">
            @{randomImg = random.Next(1, Casual);}
            <img src="~/content/images/map/@jobTitleModel.ImageType.ImageTypeOption/img@(randomImg).svg" type="image/svg+xml" />
            <form method="post" asp-page="/UIMain/Requirements/Index" asp-page-handler="ShowImg" asp-route-ID="@jobTitleModel.JobTitleId">
                <input type="hidden" name="ImgId" value="@randomImg" />
                <input type="submit" class="btnhidden" />
            </form>
            <a asp-page="/UIMain/Requirements/Index" asp-route-ID="@jobTitleModel.JobTitleId" asp-route-ImgId="@randomImg" class="btn btn-outline-primary mb-2 mt-1 btn-block" onclick="return myfunc(this)">@jobTitleModel.JobTitle</a>
        </div>
        break;
}
```

Handler method `ShowImg`

```
public IActionResult OnPostShowImg()
{
    //code logic here

    return Page();
}
```

Trigger form submission while clicking `<a>` tag

```
function myfunc(el) {
    $(el).prev().find("input[type='submit']").click();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my original post to show how I implemented what you suggested. I went for option 1 (asp-route-parameter) because it's just referenced an image, as you clarified in your post. Marked as Solved!